# Eclipse - remove dropdown field in file editor

Tags: eclipse

I inadvertently added this little dropdown field to the file editor in Eclipse. How can I remove it?

The tooltip for this field is "Switch frame pages or embedded documents".

[image]

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: I don't know where it came from.  I think I added it when by dragging the tab somewhere.  It is only appear on JSP files.  Other files, such as Java files, do not display this.

Comment: Did you tried resetting perspective. Right click on perspective icon on top right corner of eclipse then click reset.